# How can I make a restrictions to some words?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to make input like that: I am Programer, but if i will type wrong letter it will automatically erase it, or will not allow me to type that letter.

I have tried this kinda code: index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">  
    <title>I AM Programmer</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<form name="myForm">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required my-directive>
</form>

<!-- <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>
 -->
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function myValidation(value) {
                if (value.indexOf("I am Programmer") > -1) {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
    };
});
```

style.css

```
    body{
        background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
input.ng-invalid {
    border:2px solid #EA4335;
}
input.ng-valid {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
input{
width:800px;
height:60px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px
}
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code?

Comment: Post your `verify()` function code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want
html

```
<input name="myInput" valid-ng-model="myInput" data-ng-trim="false" required my-directive>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function ($parse) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
            function myValidation(value) {
                if ("I am Programmer".toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
                    return value;
                } else {
                    mCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.myInput);
                    mCtrl.$render();
                    mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
                }
            }
            mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('validNgModel', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        scope: true,
        link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parsedNgModel = $parse(attrs.validNgModel);
            scope.$$customNgModel = angular.copy(parsedNgModel(scope));
            element.attr('ng-model', '$$customNgModel');
            element.removeAttr('valid-ng-model');
            var compiledElement = $compile(element)(scope);
            var ngModelCtrl = compiledElement.controller('ngModel');
            scope.$watch('$$customNgModel', function (newModelValue) {
                if (ngModelCtrl.$valid || ngModelCtrl.$error.required) {
                    parsedNgModel.assign(scope.$parent, newModelValue);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zinduyaar/6zok0oee/6/)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use **$validators**. Below is the sample, inline with your example.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {})
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
        mCtrl.$validators.strictCheck = function(modelVal) {
          var regex = /^I am Programmer$/;
          if (regex.test(modelVal)) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required my-directive>
    <span ng-if="myForm.myInput.$error.required">
      Required!
    </span>
    <span ng-if="myForm.myInput.$error.strictCheck">
      Please input 'I am Programmer'
    </span>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

You can modify RegExp accordingly, to match your need. You can also set the input value using **$setViewValue(modelValue)** and **$render()**

```
mCtrl.$setViewValue("");
mCtrl.$render();
```

Comment: my code does same thing too, but if you will type wrong letter for example: I sm Programmer it should automatically erase wrong letter - > I am Pro-f-(f removed) and left only I am Pro.

and where should i user mCtrl.$setViewValue and $render ?

Comment: mCtrl.$setViewValue and $render can be used when your regex test fails, but in you case it wont apply. I think you should reset the value on blur of the input field